# Propagation delay of ripple carry adder

Tags: delay, adder

I am having a hard time grasping the propagation delay of the full ripple carry adder. Suppose I have n adders and for each adder, the inputs are An, Bn.

Please help me with this question:
As the adder depends on the carry generated from the previous adder, the propagation delay is the same for all combinations of inputs (A0, ..., An) and (B0, ..., Bn), right?

I am confused because the way we calculate the carry output and sum for each stage is the same using S = A xor B xor C and Cout = AB + Cin(A xor B)

Comment: Technically, you can arrange things so that a full adder has the same delay to the SUM output as it does to the CARRY-OUT output. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TByDB.png). Since the CARRY-OUT is an input to the next higher-order bit adder, the ripple-carry process adds a delay. Suppose two bits. The first FA imposes a delay of 1 (whatever length that is). This then adds a delay to the CARRY-IN of the 2nd stage, which also adds its own delay of 1. So the full 2-bit output is ready after a delay of 2 in this case. What's the question?

Comment: The basic C-MOS gate is the And-Or-Invert gate. Instead of building a ripple carry adder from chained ("conventional") full adders (Cout = Not(Not(AB + ACin+BCin))), you can build it from pairs of adders, one with inverted Cout feeding one with inverted Cin. You save one inversion/one inverter delay per bit, two per pair. I find this ignored all too often in comparisons between "conventional ripple carry adders" with suggested improvements.

Comment: @periblepsis Hi, sorry for the confusing question. I just want to ask if the propagation delay is the same for every combination of inputs, then we have critical path or worst-case delay for any values of {A0,..., An}, {B0, ..., Bn} right?

Comment: `if the propagation delay is the same for every combination of inputs, then …` That's not how it works. You have 2 *n* inputs for 2 summands, + possibly a *carry in*. You have *n* outputs, maybe a *carry out* on top. Changing one input at a time, the delay until the last output settles is *very* different depending on *which* input changed. Same weight inputs will be similar, maybe identical. A change from 0 to 1 should experience a delay similar to one from 1 to 0. With a ripple carry scheme, lowest weight inputs to highest weight outputs will be slowest - there is a *critical path* there.